# Can not using attribute to correlate message using wso2 bpel

Tags: wso2, bpel

I use Wso2 BPS to write an asynchronous workflow. To correlate the request and the callback I use an element in the request and an attribute in the callback. The definitions of the correlator is:

- For the request

  < bpws:property name="correlatorProp" type="xs:string"/>
         < bpws:propertyAlias propertyName="tns:correlatorProp" messageType="ws-drt:pushIn" part="params">

  < bpws:query>< ![CDATA[/drt-type:resources/res:resource/res:uuid]]>< / pws:query>
  < /bpws:propertyAlias>
- For the callback:

  < bpws:propertyAlias propertyName="tns:correlatorProp" messageType="ws-dpalert:pushIn" part="params">
      < bpws:query>< ![CDATA[@conversationId]]>< /bpws:query>
  < /bpws:propertyAlias>

Then I test this workflow with the below request/callback

- Request 
  < soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  < soapenv:Body>
      < type:push xmlns:res="http://esa.int/sais-dpc/schema/resource" timestamp="2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z" sequenceNumber="1" lastResponse="true">
          < type:resources>
              
              < res:resource>
                  < res:uuid>40000< /res:uuid>
          < /type:resources>
      < /type:push>
  < /soapenv:Body>
  < /soapenv:Envelope>
- Callback:

< soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    < soapenv:Body>
        < p:push xmlns:p="http://esa.int/sais-dpc/service/specification/dp-alert-provider/type" conversationId="40000" sequenceNumber="0" lastResponse="true">
            < p:alertsRef>40000< /p:alertsRef>
        < /p:push>
    < /soapenv:Body>
< /soapenv:Envelope>

But the engine failed to correlate the two messages. Is there any body have experience that issue?

Thanks,

Minh Tri.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce this issue and created a [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-13440) to track the issue. We will fix this issue in a future release of WSO2 BPS.

Currently the only workaround is to use an Element value as the correlation property alias.

Comment: I fixed the issue in trunk. You can try out the latest snapshot build from - http://wso2.org/bamboo/browse/WSO2CARBON-PRODUCTS